# c++ winrt uwp how to get value out of dependency property

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, c++17, c++-winrt

Given a dependency property in a Custom attached property defined in it's class as

```cpp
   private:
            static Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty m_IsOpenProperty;
```

I have tried,

```cpp
bool FlyoutCloser::GetIsOpen(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const& target)
    {
        return target.GetValue(m_IsOpenProperty).as<bool>();

    }
```

however here the compiler is telling me 
`C++ no suitable conversion function from to exists converting from winrt::impl::com_ref<bool> to "bool" exists.` How can I get a boolean value out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target.GetValue()` will return an IInspectable type, you need to use winrt::unbox_value function to unbox an IInspectable back into a scalar value instead of using `as` method. And about boxing and unboxing, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/boxing).

```
bool FlyoutCloser::GetIsOpen(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const& target)
{
    return winrt::unbox_value<bool>(target.GetValue(m_IsOpenProperty));
}

void FlyoutCloser::SetIsOpen(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const& target, bool value)
{
    target.SetValue(m_IsOpenProperty, winrt::box_value(value));
}
```